# How to get consistent datetime object from human date?

Tags: python, datetime, nlp, datetime-format, python-datetime

I want to convert human scheduling dialogue such as:

- 30 minutes from now or 30 minutes
- Tomorrow from 7 to 8 Pm
- one and half hour

To datetime objects or duration. I was able to find useful python packages such as [timefhuman](https://github.com/alvinwan/timefhuman) and [dateparser](https://github.com/scrapinghub/dateparser) but all of them can only do few things not all.

Example:

```
print(timefhuman('30 minutes'))
```

Gives:

```
return TimeToken(relative_hour=hour, minute=minute, time_of_day=time_of_day)
  File "/Users/Daniyal/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/timefhuman/data.py", line 297, in __init__
    assert 0 <= self.hour < 24
AssertionError
```

While `print(dateparser.parse('30 minutes'))`
Gives:

```
2021-03-28 12:46:08.979070
```

Which is in its own format (past vs future) which makes an app breakable and hard to scale if I were to use both.
Such as this case where:

```
print(timefhuman('1.5 hour'))
```

Gives:

```
2021-01-05 00:00:00
```

while:

```
print(dateparser.parse('1.5 hour'))
```

Gives:

```
2021-03-28 08:38:27.310565
```

which the results are completely different.

& sometimes none give an answer for strings such as 'One and half hour'.

How should I go about this? given that each have their own limitation and even when used together the results are different.

Comment: https://www.mturk.com/

Comment: [pytimeparse](https://github.com/wroberts/pytimeparse) might help with the timedeltas

Comment: @MrFuppes Doesn't generate output for text such as "2 and half hours"